# Find Bounding Box of a 3d point cloud using PCA

Tags: vector, pca, svd, point-clouds, jama

I'm trying to find a bounding box of a 3d point cloud using PCA.
I'm using the JAMA "Java Matrix Package" in order to perform SVD.

1. I'm sampling 1000 out of my point cloud and perform SVD:

   > ```
   > Matrix pointsMatrix = new Matrix(nThPoints);
   > SingularValueDecomposition svd = new SingularValueDecomposition(pointsMatrix);
   > ```
2. I'm extracting the 3 PCA vectors from the result and adding their negatives:

   > double[] vector1 = {svd.getU().get(0, 0), svd.getU().get(1, 0),
   >   svd.getU().get(2, 0)};                 double[] vector1N = Vec.Mult(vector1,
   >   -1);
   >                 double[] vector2 = {svd.getU().get(0, 1), svd.getU().get(1, 1), svd.getU().get(2, 1)};
   >                 double[] vector2N = Vec.Mult(vector2, -1);
   >                 double[] vector3 = {svd.getU().get(0, 2), svd.getU().get(1, 2), svd.getU().get(2, 2)};
   >                 double[] vector3N = Vec.Mult(vector3, -1);
3. I'm magnifying each vector according to the data dimensions (going through each of the 1000 points and checking what is the biggest projection):

   vector1 = Vec.projectData(vector1, nThPoints);

   ```
       vector1N = Vec.projectData(vector1N, nThPoints);
       vector2 = Vec.projectData(vector2, nThPoints);
       vector2N = Vec.projectData(vector2N, nThPoints);
       vector3 = Vec.projectData(vector3, nThPoints);
       vector3N = Vec.projectData(vector3N, nThPoints);
   ```

Now, that I have 6 new vectors I need somehow to calculate the 8 corners (while remembering the sample center) and I just don't know how to do that.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a detailed description here:

http://hewjunwei.wordpress.com/2013/01/26/obb-generation-via-principal-component-analysis/